# two listtView are overlapping on same screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I have two **listView** and they are overlapping on same screen.I have  tried with **singleChildScrollView** also.
How to solve this issue and thanks in advance.
The code

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Stack(
                children: [
                  if(submittedComment.isNotEmpty)...[
                    ListView.builder(itemCount: submittedComment.length,shrinkWrap: true, scrollDirection: Axis.vertical, itemBuilder: (context,index){
                   return Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-150,
                        child: Card(
                          child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children:[]
                              )
                            )
                          )
                       });
                  ],
    ListView.builder(
                itemCount: widget.snapshot.comments.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                itemBuilder: (context, j) {
                  return Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-150,
                  
                    child: Card(
                      child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: []
                       )
                     )
                     );
                  })
)
)
}
```

Comment: Please share screenshot of what you want and what you got with this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change Stack to Column. And put in to ListViews `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`. Then Wrap Column with SingleChildScrollView().

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Stack` and use `Column` instead.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: [
             ListView.builder(),
             ListView.builder()
]))}
```